# PhpStorm $_POST always empty

Tags: php, post, wamp, phpstorm, php-ini

`$_POST` seems that does not work. I've installed PhpStorm 10.0.3, and using the WAMP server default php interpreter.

in the index.php:

```
<form method='post' action='a.php'>
    <input type='text' name='user_f'>
    <input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'>
</form>
```

In the a.php:

```
var_dump($GLOBALS);
```

when I type "asdf" in the form:

```
array (size=9)
      'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' => string 'user_f=asdf&send=Send' (length=22)
      '_GET' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '_POST' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '_COOKIE' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '_FILES' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '_ENV' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      '_REQUEST' => 
        array (size=0)
```

`$_GET` works good, but seems like the interpreter don´t fill the `$_POST` variable.

php.version: 5.4.12 (same problem using 5.6.18 and 7 interpreters from http://php.net/downloads.php )

php.ini file for this version:(default from wamp)

Other ports like (3306) for MySQL works good in the PhpStorm. (Connection with phpmyadmin is ok)

Xdebug port : 9000 PhpStorm built-in server port: 63342

Everything works good if i build from Netbeans IDE in the default localhost:8000

Same problem in my laptop.

Comment: Use Apache from WAMP (or any other proper web server) to serve your web requests. Right now you are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server which ATM has issues with handling POST requests.

Comment: Actual (main) ticket on JB Issue Tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317 . In addition to using proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc) you can also use PHP's own web server (can be launched using "PHP Built-in Web Server" type of Run/Debug Configuration)

Comment: Built-in Sever finally works !!! thank you!!

Comment: Can also confirm this issue for PhpStorm for macSierra, issue only occurs within the IDE for post requests. Placing my php post request in my xampp's folder works fine.

Answer (score 2):

The new PhpStorm 2017.2.2 EAP build (172.3968.23) has solved this problem.

Bug [WEB-17317](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317)  502 Bad Gateway error from the server when post data.

You can download it [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program).

Complete Release notes 
link=>confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+EAP+172.3968.23+Release+Notes

Answer (score 0):

Paste this workaround in your page's initialization to use `$_POST` as normal:

```
<?php
//required when using PhpStorm's built-in webserver
//which always makes $_POST empty
//and must have .ini setting always_populate_raw_post_data = -1
//but will NOT work with enctype="multipart/form-data"
$raw_str = file_get_contents('php://input'); //eg. name1=val&name2=val
if($raw_str) {
    foreach (explode('&', $raw_str) as $pair) {
        $keyvalue = explode("=", $pair);
        $key = urldecode($keyvalue[0]);
        $value = urldecode($keyvalue[1]);
        $_POST[$key] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter with PHPSTORM, HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA can store unrecognized data from request, have a try , content-type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded add to Http headers;

Answer (score -2):

Try setting the `enctype` of the form, without it the `$_POST` array might not be populated as PHP only receives a string of fields without knowing what to do with it:

```
<form method='post' action='a.php' enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='text' name='user_f'>
    <input type='submit' name='send' value='Send'>
</form>
```

Comment: Your solution is not related to the subject of the discussion.