# Form submit is not posting dynamic created fields by jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, phpstorm

Actually I am generating input fields for HTML-Form dynamically.
Now my problem is when submit the form nothing will be post to my php.

So when I am using

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
```

in my php there is an empty array.

Here is my html-form:

```
<form method="POST" action="../php/saveTraining.php" id="trainingForm">
    <section id="mainCategory" class="hidden">
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mainCat" id="Krafttraining">Krafttraining</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" name="mainCat" id="Joggen">Joggen</label>
    </section>
    <section id="categoryKrafttraining" class="hidden">
        <label class="subCategory"><input type="checkbox" class="subCategory">Kurzhantel</label>
        <label class="subCategory"><input type="checkbox" class="subCategory">Bankdrücken</label>
    </section>
    <section id="categoryJoggen" class="hidden">
        <label><input type="number" name="joggingKm" id="joggingKm">Kilometer</label>
        <label><input type="number" name="joggingTime" id="joggingTime">Zeit</label>
    </section>
    <input type="hidden" id="saveTraining" name="sent" value="save">
</form>
```

you can ignore the 3rd section, because actually I am not working with it.

So here is the .js code where I create the additional fields:

```
('#'+ category +' :checkbox').off('change').change(function (event) {
        console.log("YUP");
        sectionID = 'sect'+ $(event.target.parentNode).text();
        if (this.checked){
            //append input fields
            $('#'+category).append( '<section id='+sectionID+'><h5>'+$(event.target.parentNode).text()+'</h5><label><input type="number" name="saetze" id="saetze">Sätze</label>' +
                                            '<label><input type="number" name="wiederholungen" id="wiederholungen">Wiederholungen</label></section>');
        }else{
            console.log("HIER");
            //delete not necessary input fields
            $('#'+sectionID).remove();

        }
    });
```

here is my .php connection :

```
<?php
$host= "127.0.0.1";
$user= "censored";
$pw= "censored";
$db= "censored";


$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "$db", "$user", "$pw", 3306);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") ";
}

echo $mysqli->host_info . "\n";
```

?>

and here is the .php that get called from form submit:

```
<?php
include ('datenbankConnect.php');

$saetze = $_POST['saetze'];
$wiederholungen = $_POST['wiederholungen'];
echo "werte:";
echo $saetze;
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
?>
```

So when submitting the form I also get the following message from my php:

> Notice: Undefined index:
> Notice: Undefined index:

Maybe you could help me. It would be great!

So there is a problem with `method="post"`. When I am using `method="get"` and accordingly changing the php to GET everything works fine.

So could it be possible that POST is not working for PhpStorm's integrated server?

---

## SOLVED

The problem was that PhpStorm's integrated server have some issues with POST method. With GET everything works fine.

And guys, don´t forget to give your input types names ;)

Comment: the names of the inputs have to be unique, I guess that's the problem.

Comment: I guess you`re talking about the name="maincat" ?
I deleted it for testing your theory, but it has no effect there is still an empty POST array.

Comment: right now I gave all inputs a name, but it has no effect

Comment: If you solve just answer your question and apply that answer

Comment: @webbie Please post your solution as an answer -- it will be helpful for other users in similar situation. Do not hesitate to link any similar questions that led you to discovering this fact (there are quite a few questions with the same issue, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39552876/php-post-not-working-properly or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37052537/post-empty-when-using-intellij -- see my comments for example)

Answer (score 0):

What is output of:

```
echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
```

If you don't have **saetze** in your post array you should inspect HTML code with firebug or chrome devTools to see if your javascript code is working properly.

Comment: hello output of it is empty!
but when I am changing the form method to "GET" and also change it in my php everything works fine.
So I am using phpStorm integrated Server could this be the reason why POST method is not working?