# Strange issue with post in PHP Storm

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I want to print out the data from `$_POST`, but for some reason the PHP side isn't receiving the data when I do [POST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29).

Here's the super simple code in a file called `test.php`

```
<?php
    echo "<b>GET </b>";
    print_r($_GET);
    echo "<br><b>POST </b>";
    print_r($_POST);
?>

<html>
    <body>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name"><br>
            <input type="text" name="email"><br>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I visit `http://localhost:63342/pastr/test.php` and fill in a name and email and click submit the information does get posted. I checked from Chrome's network tab and saw that the data is getting posted like `name=this+should+get+posted+as+name&email=this+should+get+posted+as+email`.

Here's a screenshot of the full headers in case the issue might be hidden there: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEtga.png

Everything seems to be working except the webpage displays this:

```
GET Array ( )
POST Array ( )
```

The POST array is somehow empty? What have I done wrong?

Note, this works fine if I change the method to [GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods), when I change to get I see this:

```
GET Array ( [name] => this should be name [email] => this should be email )
POST Array ( )
```

**My question is**: What am I doing wrong here in trying to print out the POST-ed data and how can I fix it so that I can print out the received name and email?

Note: trying `echo $_POST['name']` and `echo $_POST['email']` both result in a very similar errors: `Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\2\g\pastr\test.php on line 8`
`Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\2\g\pastr\test.php on line 9`

Comment: Your code has no error , it works as it is and I can also see the post data

Comment: I guess the problem must be with my php configuration then? If it helps I'm running it through PhpStorm, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: I am not sure... try using print_r($_REQUEST);

Comment: that output `Array ( )` for the POST request and `Array ( [name] => asdasd [email] => asdasd )` for the GET request

Comment: Yes i see that in your question .. just want to make sure if  $_REQUEST too is working or not

Comment: that is the output of $_REQUEST

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290133/phpstorm-post-always-empty-solved  ??

Comment: The sample code/HTML does not result in valid HTML. Everything must be within the `<html></html>` tags (and in this case also within the `<body></body>` tags). Run the generated page (e.g. from view source in the browser) through [a HTML validator](http://validator.w3.org/) ("Validate by direct input" for that particular validator).

Comment: Did it work when using Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Apache from WAMP (or any other proper web server) to serve your web requests. Right now you are using PhpStorm's own built-in simple web server which ATM has issues with handling POST requests.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

The script is correct, and it should work, if the Web server actually processes the same `test.php`. Try to use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` instead of the hard-coded `test.php`:

```php
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: I wonder if people still use `get` to send data. I have seen many online articles not in favour of this.