# php login form not receiving form data

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I'm new to PHP and have started a mini project.

This may sound extremely dumb but I can't get the values from my form.

Any idea on the problem?

My form:

```
<div class='panel-body'>
    <form class='form-horizontal' action='test.php' method='post' role='form'>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='username' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Username</label>
            <div class='col-sm-10'>
                <input type='text' class='form-control' id='username' name='username' placeholder='Username' required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <label for='password' class='col-sm-2 control-label'>Password</label>
            <div class='col-sm-10'>
                <input type='password' class='form-control' id='password' name='password' placeholder='Password' required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
                <div class='checkbox'>
                    <label><input type='checkbox'> Remember me</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class='form-group'>
            <div class='col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10'>
                <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' id='btn-login' name='btn-login'>Sign in</button>
            </div>
       </div>
   </form>
```

The PHP file (test.php)...

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
    echo $_POST['username'];
} else {
    echo 'doom';
}
```

Comment: try var_dump($_POST) and tell me what you see

Comment: yes indeed @FrayneKonok and both files are stored on the same directory level.

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST); try it

Comment: @Kaushalshah vardump print array(0) { }

Comment: @FrayneKonok isset($_POST['btn-login']) still doesn't work.

Comment: @Kaushalshah  
print_r($_REQUEST returns ( [SQLiteManager_currentLangue] => 2 )

Comment: Pasted the code into PHPfiddle and it works as expected. The Password field is required, remember.

Comment: i think your form is not properly submitted.

Comment: I created a local test case by copy/pasting your code and could not reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Quentin strange. Can you think of what may be causing this on my local machine. I can upload to my domain to check this. one moment ...

Comment: Are you putting a value in the password field as well as your username? Otherwise the form will not submit.

Comment: @Henders yes of course.

Comment: @Quentin you're correct, I added the documents to http://josephaspey.com/login.php and it works. Is this a problem with how many directories lie in phpStorm?

Comment: @FrayneKonok this does not fix my problem, it is a work-around but does not solve my problem. I'd like to keep my code seperate, so the code that verifies the login is not in the same file as the login page. However, thanks for your assistance. I've uploaded my files to josephaspey.com/login.php and it works. so the problem lies with my local machine. Can you think of any reason this may occur. A possible directory error? I'm using phpStorm as in IDE.

Comment: Could you have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35290133/phpstorm-post-always-empty) and tell us if that is the issue you are experiencing? Looks like there might have been a bug in PHPStorm with post requests..

Comment: And what version of PHP and PHPstorm are you using?

Comment: @Henders cheers for the reference. Im current using php 7.0.0 and PhpStrom 10.0.4

Comment: I am stumped. The only thing I can think of is to try it with WAMP and substitute that for the PHPStorm server. Then at least you know where the problem lies. The code is valid. Do you know the HTTP response code that you are getting from the POST request? Try looking in the access log to see. If it's 200 then I really am stumped.